# How can I use a Portable Hard Drive label name instead of the Drive Letter?

Tags: batch-file, label, drive

So here's my problem. 
I'm making a batch (working from inside the hard drive) to open a hided system folder on the hard drive, and with that two .vbs files. It all works great, but when I go to another computer with the same hard drive, obviously the drive letter changes so my code doesn't open the folder I need, but instead any other one from the computer that attempts to use the batch.

So I need to make it open the Hard Drive, by his name. Which is Albandart.

How can I change this code to work with the label name of the hard drive?

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "A:\System\PAOutput"
@explorer A:\SystemFiles\PAe.vbs
@explorer A:\SystemFiles\PAs.vbs
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Your code does _not_ use any label name. If you want to "Get the Drive Letter of the Portable Hard Drive that contain the running Batch file", then just use this format: `%~D0`. For example: `@explorer %~D0\SystemFiles\PAe.vbs`

Comment: `wmic Volume where Label="Albandart" get DeviceID` returns the letter of the drive labelled `Albandart`; capture its output by `for /F` and assign it to a variable...

Comment: Are you running the batch file from the portable drive?